# R Lauguage read.csv numeric with decimal

Tags: r, read.csv

Good afternoon, everyone,
While importing csv file into R using read.csv or fread, I noticed that second number after decimal was cut off, such as 95.56 becomes 95.5
any ideas?
Thank you
DL

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: Loss_csv <- read.csv("loss2017.csv", head=TRUE)
str(Loss_csv)

Comment: I suspect the values are there, you simply don't see them with `str()`. Did you _study_ at the question I linked to?

Comment: Thank you, Eric. just figured it out. under str(),  just only see one digit after decimal. but if write.csv, it still actually two digits after decimal. have a good day.